# ModuleNotFoundError: Correct setup

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have the following directory structure on Windows:

```
\Code
   \ Projects
      \ProjectA
         \dev.env
         \FileA.py
   \Shared
      \ModA
         \__init__.py
         \tools.py
```

Within my ProjectA, Im trying to import a function from tools.py for use in FileA.py using:

```
from ModA.tools import function_x
```

I have created an dev.env file in the ProjectA folder that contains a single line:

```
PYTHONPATH=C:/Code/Shared/ModA/
```

and I have set the following in VSCode Settings | Workspace Settings

```
python:Env
${workspaceFolder}/dev.env
```

But every time I try the import I get a ModuleNotFoundError

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not really a Windows user, although typically the path would be like: `PYTHONPATH=C:\Code\Shared\ModA` ( note backslash, not forwardslash )

Comment: I've tried both :)

Comment: Did you tried escaping the backslash? `C:\\Code\\Shared\\ModA`

Comment: What happens if you try just `from tools import function_x`?

Comment: @Freddy yes, I have tried escaping the \

Comment: @l'L'l that produces the same error

Comment: In `FileA.py` put the following at the top and post the output `import sys ; print(sys.path[0])` ... if it comes up blank then that means your path is not set to `\Code\Shared\ModA`.

Comment: it returns the path to the ProjectA folder

Comment: is there a way to check that the PYTHONPATH is getting set correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the `launch.json` file following [this steps](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations) and add this line:

```
"envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/dev.env"
```

Your `.vscode/launch.json` should look like this:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/dev.env"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Make sure to change the `python.envFile` option in the Workspace settings (`.vscode/settings.json`) to `${workspaceFolder}/dev.env`

Acording to the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file):

> You can then set the python.envFile setting to
>   ${workspaceFolder}/prod.env, then set the envFile property in the
>   debug configuration to ${workspaceFolder}/dev.env.

---

And change the import to:

```
from tools import function_x
```

Comment: Hi @Freddy  I already have `${workspaceFolder}/dev.env` set as mentioned in OP. Are you talking about something different to that?

Comment: You mention `python:Env`, do you mean `python.envFile`?

Comment: if you type python.env in the settings it takes you to Python:Env File that says 'Absolute path to a file containing environment variable definitions'. My value there is ${workspaceFolder}/dev.env

Comment: Try creating the file `settings.json` inside the `.vscode` folder with the following: `{
  "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/dev.env"
}`

Comment: Try creating the `launch.json` file, I edited the answer to include this

Comment: Thank you, that worked.. but i am non the wiser as to why the launch.json was necessary :(

Comment: There is an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/1459) about that. For now, "... you have to set `envFile` in `launch.json` explicitly." If the answer helped you, please go ahead and mark it as "Accepted" :)